# changing dots style in slide of images with javascript

Tags: javascript, slider

I have a set of three dots that are supposed to change style when its the current dot so it will become darker than the others and the solution I found kinda works but I don't get why it doesn't work properly. 
I've google other ways of doing this but right now i'm trying to understand why the code I wrote  works in a funny way

code here  https://codepen.io/mullerz/pen/RwWVPJN

```
        <button class="botao current"></button>
        <button class="botao"></button>
        <button class="botao"></button>
    </div>

JS
dots.forEach(function(el, index){

    el.addEventListener("click",function(){

        const esta = this;
        const target = newdots.findIndex(function(num){
            return num === esta;
        })

        slides.style.transform = "translateX(" + ( - size * target) + "px";
        slides.style.transition = "transform .5s";

        document.querySelector(".current").classList.remove("current");
        this.classList.add("current");

    })
})
```

Thanks a million

Comment: Hi @peter, I tried running your Codepen link and the `current` class is applied properly to the active slide. Could you explain more what's the issue? You can use `border:none` and `outline:none` properties on `.botao` class to make dots more visible.

Comment: Hey @Akansh when I first open it the first dot is selected (it has by default the current style applied) when I click the second button both first and second buttons get the current style and when I click the third button the second and the third get the current style applied .  So only after clicking in every button several times the codes appears to work fine but in the beginning I always get two buttons with the current style